# Opening Office Web Apps Documents in Browser - 'view in browser' doesn't work but 'edit in browser' does

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I installed Office Web Apps SP2 on our SharePoint 2010 farm this past weekend.  I've observed that the service applications have been created and I've activated the feature at the site collection level.  The word viewing service is started on all my WFE machines.  When I access word documents from a library by clicking them or saying "view in browser", the site brings me to a blank document.  No errors.  I just get a blank document with a very basic ribbon that belongs to Word with buttons on it for 'file', 'open in word' and 'edit in browser'. However, if I hit "Edit in Browser", the site displays the document.

I'm not finding much interesting in the Sharepoint logs, even with OWA logging turned up to verbose.  Excel documents come up fine in the browser without such a procedure.

I had no such issue when I installed office web apps in our TEST SP2010 farm.

Any ideas what I can look at next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The powerpoint and word reader service applications had not been created as expected by the setup.   Creating these solved our problem immediately.